# Android Crashed

Tags: unbricking

I Rooted my Alcatel One touch Glory 2S and accidently deleted JrdLauncher.apk (Android's Default Launcher). Then I made a factory reset and i thought it would help to restore it ... What i ended up was when i boot my phone, all the apps crashed with a message "Unfortunately, ... has crashed" and the homescreen went black with only a status bar on top. Tried reformattng but still no use.. now im stuck help pls ...its running android 4.1.1 jellybean...

Answer (score 2):

A "factory reset" only wipes the user data from the device: it doesn't touch the system apps or operating system at all. You need to either find the APK file you're missing (perhaps from a friend with the same phone) and install it as a system app via `adb` (since you can't use the phone normally), or find the stock ROM and reflash it onto your phone using the usual ROM-flashing process for your phone.

Comment: I tried searching the missing app in another same phone but cant copy it because it is a system app. I even tried searching up for custom ROM and found nothing for my Alcatel OneTouch Glory 2S. Please help me . Thanks In advance.